# Flutter: howto return the codePoint value from an Icon widget?

Tags: flutter, widget, icons

I want to bypass an Icon Widget to a custom widget and get the Icons codePoint value make some changes and return the new Icon Widget.

```
class NewCustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewCustomWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.mySize,
    this.myIcon,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? mySize;
  final Icon? myIcon;

  @override
  _NewCustomWidgetState createState() => _NewCustomWidgetState();
}

class _NewCustomWidgetState extends State<NewCustomWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Icon(
      ???? howto bypass the widget.myIcon's codePoint/IconData to the new Icon ????
      color: Colors.black,
      size: widget.mySize,
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use the widget.myIcon.toString() but I get only the String "widget"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Icon` takes IconData. You can do

```dart
return Icon(
  widget.myIcon?.icon,
  color: Colors.black,
  size: widget.mySize,
);
```